# Определение типа предложения

Tags: двоеточие, бсп

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться: это предложение с обобщающим словом или БСП?

> Сейчас за скалами такая картина: немногочисленные леса, горные реки,
> сельские просторы и разнообразные базы отдыха.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это 21 задание? Слово картина, конечно, вбирает в себя всё перечисленное, но считать его обобщающим, думаю, нельзя. Было бы простым предложением с обобщающим словом и однородными членами такое:

*Всё это: немногочисленные леса, горные реки, сельские просторы и разнообразные базы отдыха - вместе составляло прекрасную картину.*

Это предложение всё-таки бессоюзное сложное.

*Сейчас за скалами такая картина: (какая именно? вторая часть раскрывает содержание первой) немногочисленные леса, горные реки, сельские просторы и разнообразные базы отдыха.*  Вторая часть представляет собой 4 назывных предложения.

Сложность, видимо, в том, что ответом будут бессоюзные сложные предложения, где двоеточие ставится в соответствии с другим правилом его постановки  - когда 2-я часть является причиной.

Comment: Людмила, а вы уверены, что это назывные предложения. Мне как-то не встречались в данной теме сложные конструкции с бессоюзной связью и двоеточием. К тому же в Сети много ответов на это задание, и везде написано, что это предложение с обобщающим словом.

Comment: В науке такие конструкция называются переходными, а я при ответе не очень заморачивалась и руководствовалась тем, что в школьной грамматике обобщающим словом считается родовое понятие по отношению к цепочке однородных членов- видовых понятий. Этот же случай относится к отношениям целого и части, в школьной практике их нет. В науке - да. Почему такой случай включили в задание - неизвестно. Печально, но в ЕГЭ часты стали трудные случаи. Но, может, составители тоже особо не заморачивались, ведь ученик должен был найти одинаковые конструкции, а это предложение к ним не относится.

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ. Предложение действительно смутное  и для школьных мозгов малоподходящее. Всё-таки на экзамене надо проверять базовые знания,  а это очень частная конструкция. Но я немного не о том. Мне кажется, что природа назывных предложений несколько иная.

Comment: Это всегда изолированный ряд,  даже если там есть перечисление. Для назывных предложений нехарактерны такие связи, как пояснение или обобщение. Например, у Пушкина довольно сложный ряд назывных предложений выглядит так: Швед, русский – колет, рубит,
режет. Бой барабанный, клики, скрежет.
Гром пушек, топот, ржанье,
стон,
И смерть и ад со всех сторон.

Answer (score 2):

*Сейчас за скалами **такая картина:** немногочисленные леса, горные реки, сельские просторы и разнообразные базы отдыха.*

**1. На это задание я видела следующий ответ:** https://multiurok.ru/files/punktuatsionnyi-analiz-prakticheskie-zadaniia-21-i.html

5. В предложениях **2 и 4 двоеточие ставится согласно одному и тому же правилу**. Бессоюзная связь, значение причины (потому что).

Предложение 1 – бессоюзное со значением пояснения (а именно).

В предложении 3 двоеточие ставится перед однородными членами после обобщающего слова.

В предложении 6 двоеточие ставится перед прямой речью (цитатой).

2. **Вроде бы всё логично.**

А предложение действительно **с обобщающим словом и однородными членами.** Здесь обобщающим словом является "такая картина", его содержание раскрывает однородный ряд.
Предложение эллиптического вида, построенное по схеме: обстоятельство – подлежащее.